# How can i create this topology in cisco packet tracer?

Tags: cisco, packet-tracer

How can i create this topology in cisco packet tracer?
[image]
wiil be it look like this?
[image]

Comment: Not the same. Unfortunately packet tracer can’t do this topology.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on context/intention, that bus/pipe pictogram represents either an Ethernet layer-1 segment (classically) or a switched layer-2 segment (more modern variant).

A layer-1 segment is either created by a shared cable (for 10BASE5 or 10BASE2) or by a repeater hub. A layer-2 segment is created by a single switch or connected switches. It could also indicate a VLAN.

In your example, *LAN 1* and *LAN 2* can be represented by a switch or a VLAN each - no need to use multiple switches.

Comment: Won’t be able to configure a host with two interfaces

Comment: Yep, XP3 host should have 2 NICs. Maybe host XP3 can be replaced by a router for this simulation.

Comment: Indeed - XP3 could be working as a proxy, as a router, as a bridge/switch or even as a repeater with a shared cable variant - it all depends on the context.